# Set priority on ignite OPTIMISTIC SERIALIZABLE transactions?

Tags: ignite

Using ignite, can you set a priority on OPTIMISTIC SERIALIZABLE transactions, so one will take precedence over the other? In other words, if I have 2 optimistic serializable transactions A and B, and I know that A is more important than B, if A and B clash with each other, can I ensure that A succeeds and B fails?

The ignite [docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/transactions) say the following:

> In Ignite, each transaction is assigned a comparable version called
> XidVersion. Upon transaction commit, each entry that is written in the
> transaction is assigned a new comparable version called EntryVersion.
> An OPTIMISTIC SERIALIZABLE transaction with version XidVersionA fails
> with a TransactionOptimisticException if:
>
> - There is an ongoing PESSIMISTIC or non-serializable OPTIMISTIC transaction holding a lock on an entry of the SERIALIZABLE
>   transaction.
> - There is another ongoing OPTIMISTIC SERIALIZABLE transaction with version XidVersionB such that XidVersionB > XidVersionA and this
>   transaction holds a lock on an entry of the SERIALIZABLE transaction.

So presumably what I need to do is set XidVersion on transaction A to be higher than XidVersion on transaction B. However I can't find any way to set the XidVersion on a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite doesn't support setting transaction priorities. XidVersion is built using the natural order of a change. I.e. depending on a timeframe, the counters increases in the `order` field, it also depends on the topology and other internal things.

From the docs:

TX1 [txId=GridCacheVersion [topVer=74949328, time=1463469328421, **order**=1463469326211, nodeOrder=1], nodeId=ad68354d-07b8-4be5-85bb-f5f2362fbb88, threadId=73]

TX2 [txId=GridCacheVersion [topVer=74949328, time=1463469328421, **order**=1463469326210, nodeOrder=1], nodeId=ad68354d-07b8-4be5-85bb-f5f2362fbb88, threadId=74]